# how to upload multiple images with progress bar in asp .net mvc 4 with razor?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to upload selected multiple images at a time with showing progress bar for each in asp .net mvc 4 with razor.Please any one help

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic:

This example is self-explanatory.. Hope this helps!

Create a form for uploading multiple files:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="lblFile1">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file0" />

  <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

  <input type="submit"  value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Now in your controller post action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) {
  foreach (var file in files) {
    if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
      var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), fileName);
      file.SaveAs(path);
    }
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Upload");
}
```

**EDIT:**

I don't have much time to create a sample project with progress bar.. But this [link](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/) will definitely help you!

Comment: Can you show how to display a progress bar too, as requested?

Comment: I need to display progress bar of each image too

Comment: Oh! I can show you some example, wait for my edit.. BTW there are lots of way to do it, you can use jquery UI and ajax for displaying progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace ImageUploading.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + fileName));
                string filePath = "Images/" + fileName;
                ViewBag.message = "Image Uploaded Succesfully ";
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewBag.message = "Image Uploading Failed";
            }
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```